# Automated PayPal payments on site event

Tags: php, paypal

I'm making payments in my site that give you in site money. So a user can choose how much money he wants to transfer to his site account.

I'd like to have the option when a user has less than for example 20USD automaticly to initiate a transfer from his account to my and refill his credit in my website. Is that possible and how it can be done? I'd like to make that with paypal. Thanks

Comment: I already have IPN setup. IPN is only for the notifications (correct me if I'm wrong). I need when users money get below 20USD (on my site)  a payment to my account to be made without user doing anything.

Comment: I suggest creating a cronjob that checks the users balance every minute and if it's below 20 usd it calls a ipn using the users paypall account.

Comment: I dont understand how IPN will help me initiate a payment from the user paypal account

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/nl/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside you could intergrate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the reference transaction concept in the PayPal where you will get the consent of the buyer by agreeing a billing agreement with them once and then you can charge them at any time my using the Billing agreement Id .

Regarding automatically transfer of the money from their account to your site account , you can set the cron job which will monitor the amount of the user's site account and will trigger a call to PayPal reference transaction API to transfer the amount from their PayPal account using the billing agreement .

You can find the documents related to reference transaction [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/) .